# php create file and send as attachment without actually creating the file

Tags: php, on-the-fly, email-attachments, file-generation

I know how to read a file on the server and attach it to an email in PHP, but I wanted to know if I could attach a file that is created by my script but not created on the server (kinda like a temp file).

So create file in memory and attach it to email.

Bonus: might need to create multiple files as well, would this be too much for the server to handle? I'm not talking GB's but like 5 files with 1000 lines each?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can do that, as long as whatever email library you're using supports it. If you're not using one, you should be!
No, 5 files won't be too much for your server unless you bought it in 1993.

Hopefully your lib won't need a file reference - you can do something like:

```
$myEmail->attachData('file.name', 'mime/type', $data);
```

If it does need a file path then you could use a [php://memory](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) file:

```
 $f = fopen('php://memory/myfile', 'w');
 fwrite($f, '...');
 fclose($f);

$myEmail->attach('php://memory/myFile');
```

Comment: How would I get the file reference when doing something like this?

Comment: AntonioCS is has been the excepted answer since October 5, 2009. Did you post this comment in error?

Comment: are you sure about that usage? PHP documentation isn't great for these wrappers - and i tried using 'php://memory/foo' and i get 'invalid url' errors on fopen

Comment: In PHPMailer the method is AddStringAttachment(). You can read more about it here http://phpdocs.epesi.org/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.html#methodAddStringAttachment