# Using a php://memory wrapper causes errors

Tags: php, wrapper

I'm trying to extend the PHP mailer class from Worx by adding a method which allows me to add attachments using string data rather than path to the file.

I came up with something like this:

```
public function addAttachmentString($string, $name='', $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/octet-stream')
{
  $path = 'php://memory/' . md5(microtime());
  $file = fopen($path, 'w');
  fwrite($file, $string);
  fclose($file);

  $this->AddAttachment($path, $name, $encoding, $type);
}
```

However, all I get is a PHP warning:

```
PHP Warning:  fopen() [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: Invalid php:// URL specified
```

There aren't any decent examples with the original documentation, but I've found a couple around the internet (including [one here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522066/php-create-file-and-send-as-attachment-without-actually-creating-the-file/1522086#1522086)), and my usage appears correct according to them.

Has anyone had any success with using this?

My alternative is to create a temporary file and clean up - but that will mean having to write to disc, and this function will be used as part of a large batch process and I want to avoid slow disc operations (old server) where possible. This is only a short file but has different information for each person the script emails.

Comment: I am waaay to late on this, but wouldn't memory buffers be deleted on fclose()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickly looking at http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php and the source code, I don't see support for the "/' . md5(microtime());" bit.

Sample Code:

```
<?php
print "Trying with md5\n";
$path = 'php://memory/' . md5(microtime());
$file = fopen($path, 'w');
if ($file)
{
    fwrite($file, "blah");
    fclose($file);
}
print "done - with md5\n";

print "Trying without md5\n";
$path = 'php://memory';
$file = fopen($path, 'w');
if ($file)
{
    fwrite($file, "blah");
    fclose($file);
}
print "done - no md5\n";
```

Output:

```
buzzbee ~$ php test.php 
Trying with md5

Warning: fopen(): Invalid php:// URL specified in test.php on line 4

Warning: fopen(php://memory/d2a0eef34dff2b8cc40bca14a761a8eb): failed to open stream: operation failed in test.php on line 4
done - with md5
Trying without md5
done - no md5
```

Comment: hmm... yeah, i tried this as well - one problem I had is that I didn't get the content attached. That might be because phpmailer is using the wrong method for this thing... I have just realised that there is an AddStringAttachment method already in phpmailer (solves immediate problem) - but it's nice to learn about the php://memory wrapper

Comment: $path = 'php://memory/' . md5(microtime()); breaks everything, you need to use $path = 'php://memory';

Comment: its fails because you are closing file descriptor, as written in manual !
**php://memory and php://temp are not reusable, i.e. after the streams have been closed there is no way to refer to them again. **
use `rewind($file);` insteaf `fclose($file);` !

Answer (score 20):

It's just `php://memory`. For example,

```
<?php
    $path = 'php://memory';
    $h = fopen($path, "rw+");
    fwrite($h, "bugabuga");
    fseek($h, 0);
    echo stream_get_contents($h);
```

yields "bugabuga".

Comment: remember that `rewind($h);` and `fseek($h, 0);` is same !

Answer (score 1):

The problem here simply [**is the type and the syntax**](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php):

> `php://memory` and `php://temp` are **read-write streams** that allow temporary data to be stored **in a file-like wrapper**. The only difference between the two is that `php://memory` will always store its data in memory, whereas `php://temp` will use a temporary file once the amount of data stored hits a predefined limit (the default is 2 MB). The location of this temporary file is determined in the same way as the `sys_get_temp_dir()` function.

In short, the type you want is `temp` instead and the syntax you want is:

```
php://temp/maxmemory:$limit
```

The `$limit` is in bytes. You want to count that using [safe byte functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php).

Comment: so if I use something like fopen('php://temp/maxmemory:1048576', 'w'), what will be my 'filepath' then? The whole "'php://temp/maxmemory:1048576'" ? I need this filepath to use in other functions. Thanks

Comment: @Andrew Check `sys_get_temp_dir()` … or even better: Open a new question, reference this question and answer there.