# Why does reading from a php://memory wrapper I've just written to fail?

Tags: php

I'm trying to read from the `php://memory` wrapper using `fread()` but `fread()` always returns false. My code is simplified:

```
$file_handle = fopen('php://memory', 'w+'); // Have tried php:temp also.
fwrite($file_handle, 'contents');
$file = fread($file_handle, filesize($file_handle)); // Have also tried 99999 for filesize.
```

`$file` always is false after the `fread()`.

What's going on?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to rewind($file_handle) after writing before you can read what you've just written, because writing moves the file pointer to the end of the file

Comment: Ahhh, you beat me for 33 seconds!

Answer (score 3):

Call `rewind($file_handle)` before `fread()`

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2987330/2271704

I need to call `rewind($file_handle)` before I call `fread()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting this:

> Warning: filesize() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given

And those are the [the first problem](http://php.net/filesize):

> `int filesize ( string $filename )` —  Gets the size for the given file.

... and the second one: you haven't enabled error reporting.

Third problem is that your pointer is at the end of the file. Try something like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
// ...

rewind($file_handle);
$file = ''; //
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $file .= fread($file_handle, 8192);
}
```

Comment: Ahh yes, you are correct, filesize() does expect a file name, in my original code I was using strlen().

And again you are correct, I do have to rewind()!